# What energy is transferred into potential?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential, work, potential-energy

This question could be really out of the blue and might receive lots of downvotes, but bugging me quite a time and would appreciate your thoughts easily explained.

We know that when we do work against nature force, we increase the potential energy of an object. Lifting a ball and putting it on the table increases potential energy of it as my putting work into it is transferred to the ball's potential energy.

So as a sum up, for something to gain potential energy, some work must be done externally in opposite of nature. The same happens with charges. Taking away negative charge from positive increases potential energy of negative charge.

It's all clear till this point, but if we imagine that worm by default appeared on a mountain, how would it have potential energy? As I understand, some external work must be done so the work is transfered/converted into its potential energy. What energy is transfered into worm's potential energy? I don't believe that gravitation itself gives potential energy to the worm.

Comment: What is always physically relevant is differences in energy, it being defined up to an additive constant. What makes sense is that the worm has more potential energy when it is high in the mountain than low in the mountain. Part of the difference can be converted to kinetic energy if it tumbles down the slope for example.

Comment: You are trying to apply physics to a non-physical scenario - a worm "just appearing" on a mountainside violates the laws of nature. You might as well start from the premise that objects fall up away from the earth and ask why. There is no "why" or "how" for things that cannot happen in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A worm doesn’t magically appear on a mountain. It either hatches there or crawls there. If it hatches there then the energy was provided from the energy of the parent. If it crawls there then the energy was provided by its food. Either way, the energy always comes from somewhere, just like the worm itself always comes from somewhere.

Comment: amazing answer. could you bring the same explanation for 2 opposite charges ? if we quickly put 2 charges(positive, negative) on a paper, why would negative charge have potential energy ? what energy got transfered into its PE ?

Comment: @OmarShekriladze charges, like worms, also don’t magically appear. The energy comes from whatever brought them to the piece of paper.